# Do we need a [Records] tag

Tags: discussion, tags

An increasingly popular style of question is the format:

> [What/Who/Which] is the [longest/most/biggest] **Thingy** in television/film

We have a couple of tags these questions can *sometimes* fall into such as [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance), [cinema-history](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/cinema-history) or [most-appearances](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/most-appearances), but there's still some fall-through or cases where both are appropriate.

Even if you ignore everything in those tags, I've identified [10 questions](http://data.stackexchange.com/movies/query/218216/questions-about-records-movies-tv) which would fit in this category on their own, but arguably all [most-appearances](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/most-appearances) and [first-appearance](https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/first-appearance)s are also `records`.

So to the actual discussion:

1. Do you agree we need a records tag for at least those 10 question?
2. Do you think records should be created as a main tag and use first and most appearances as synonyms?
3. Any other solutions?

Comment: Hmm, while the idea of a dedicated tag isn't too bad, I don't like the name `records` in particular. It comes across a bit too "trivia-encouraging" (for lack of a better term), though this might be subjective impression due to a more or less general disinterest in this whole category on my part. Other than that, I also think `most-` and `first-` deserve their own tags anyway and shouldn't be synonyms.